InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Executing an update/delete query in spring batch
I am using spring batch. When I am going to update any row from witter, it shows below error:
        org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Executing an update/delete query
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:400)
        .......

    Caused by: jakarta.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.checkTransactionNeededForUpdateOperation(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:471)
        at org.hibernate.query.spi.AbstractQuery.executeUpdate(AbstractQuery.java:633)
    .......
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
        ... 48 common frames omitted

Here is my code:

my application.properties
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/testdb
spring.datasource.username=test
spring.datasource.password=test

logging.level.root=INFO
logging.level.org.hibernate.stat=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size = 2000
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_updates=true
spring.batch.job.chunk.size=10


#update for serialization
spring.datasource.hikari.isolation=READ_COMMITTED
spring.batch.jdbc.schema=always
spring.batch.jdbc.initialize-schema=always
spring.batch.jdbc.isolation-level-for-create=read_committed
spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize=10


Here is Batch configuration:
@Configuration
public class BatchBean {
   .......

   @Bean
    public JobRepository jobRepository(DataSource dataSource, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) throws Exception {
        JobRepositoryFactoryBean jobRepositoryFactoryBean = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
        jobRepositoryFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        jobRepositoryFactoryBean.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
        jobRepositoryFactoryBean.setIsolationLevelForCreate("ISOLATION_READ_COMMITTED");

        jobRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
        return jobRepositoryFactoryBean.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
    }

}


Here is my reader repository:
@Transactional
@Repository
public interface ApprovedTrxSummaryRepo extends JpaRepository<ApprovedTrxSummery, Long> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE STATUS = 17 AND  TRUNC(INSERT_DATE) = TRUNC(SYSDATE) FOR UPDATE", nativeQuery = true)
    List<ApprovedTrxSummery> getAllTransaction();

}


Here is my update operation repository:
@Transactional
@Repository
public interface ApprovedTrxSummaryRepo extends JpaRepository<ApprovedTrxSummery, Long> {

     @Modifying
    @Query(value = "update approved_trx_summery set STATUS = 2 where STATUS= 44 and TRANSACTION_REFERENCE = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
    public void updateSegmentedTransaction(String transactionReference);
}



But any update operation show above error.
Note : I have serialization error , for this reason  I have used BatchBean. But serialization does not show , but any update operation show this error.
Why it shows above the error?
Please help me...

Since you use a JPA repository to write/update items, you need to configure a JpaTransactionManager and not a DataSourceTransactionManager.
Change the transactionManager bean to a JpaTransactionManager and it should fix your issue.
